# Two inputs to C++ cin from Bash

Tags: c++, bash

I am testing the following program, where two inputs are involved, the first being a vector of int, and second being an int. 
The main.cpp file is the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> & vec) {
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) 
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> nums{}; 
    int i;
    int target;

    cout << "Please enter a vector of integers:\n";
    while (cin >> i) {
        nums.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << "Vector of Integers:" << endl;
    print(nums);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter an integer:" << endl;
    cin >> target;
    cout << "Checking whether " << target << " is in the vector...\n";
    if (find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target) != nums.end()) {
        cout << "Target found!\n"; 
    }
    else {
        cout << "Target not found!\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Bash script

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

compiles my code and creates an a.exe in the folder.
Next, I try to open it in Bash:

```
$ ./a.exe
```

Then I test it with the vector nums = {1,2,3}, and it turns out that the second cin is skipped, as you can see below.

```
Please enter a vector of integers:
1 2 3 EOF
Vector of Integers:
1 2 3
Please enter an integer:
Checking whether 0 is in the vector...
Target not found!
```

However, it is not a problem if I open the a.exe directly, without the help of the Bash terminal. So is it possible to make some changes so that it will run smoothly under Bash? 
Thanks in advance! 
P.S. I use Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input literally is

```
1 2 3 EOF
```

your program reads 1, 2, and 3 successfully. It fails to read EOF. After that, it reads nothing unless you take steps to clear the error state of `cin` and add code to read and discard the `EOF`.

You can use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` for that. You have `cin.clear()` but that still leaves `EOF` in the stream. You need to add a line to discard that from the input stream.

```
cout << "Please enter a vector of integers:\n";
while (cin >> i) {
    nums.push_back(i);
}
cout << "Vector of Integers:" << endl;
print(nums);
cin.clear();

// Need this.
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout << "Please enter an integer:" << endl;
cin >> target;
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Now the current program works just fine. It seems that we have to have the program read something "invalid" like "eof", or whatever, to terminate the process. However, after I replace all the int's with string's in my code, it does not work, no matter how I try "\n" or "\r". I think that they are both regarded as string. Is there any effective EOF options in Bash under this circumstance, equivalent to "^z" in cmd?  I am really new to Bash.

Comment: If you want to read strings, you'll have to use different approach since any non whitespace character can be read into a string. You can use `std::getline` to read  a line of text and then use `std::istringstream` to read the contents of the line to the vector.